# Google Sheets not calculating right?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

can it be that Google Sheets is not calculating right?

`=DAYS360(DATE(2016;12;31); date(2017;1;1))`

is 1 and also this is 1 but is should be 2:

```
=DAYS360(DATE(2016;12;30); date(2017;1;1))
```

[image]

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the formula that is set to 360 days. It is said here that **DAYS360 - Days between two dates on a 360-day year**. So it means that you will only have a 30 days a month not including the date 31 in the months of (Jan, March, May, July, Aug, Oct and Dec).

For example, you use this `=DAYS360(DATE(2016,10,25), date(2016,10,30))` so the expected output is **5** - which is correct

If you use `=DAYS360(DATE(2016,10,25), date(2016,10,31))` the expected output is **6** - because you specify the date 31.

But, if you use `=DAYS360(DATE(2016,10,25), date(2016,11,3))`, the output is **8** not 9 - because it did not include the date 31.

I hope I explained it clearly.